# Dietary Preparing for Morning Training

Tags: diet

Assume you want to go to the gym 0700 am. 
Should you drink proteins the evening before the morning?

I have tried to take something very short carbohydrates before training like break with sugar and some milk.
Eating too much makes the training inefficient.

**How can you prepare for the morning training during the evening before?**

Comment: Try it and see how you feel. Nobody can tell you yes or no, since every person reacts differently to things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drink the protein before *(on the same day)* the exercise. Recent studies are beginning to show that pre-workout protein intake is more effective than post-workout protein intake [*(source)*](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/ask-the-macro-manager-pre-post-workout-shakes.html). 
 
Wake up about an hour earlier, ingest your shake and go have fun :). 
 
**What you can do the evening before?**

- Get your gears ready. Don't wait till you wake up.
- Set your alarm clock; if you don't wake up in time, you cannot do anything :).
- Sleep early to refreshen your body.
- Don't forget your water bottle.
- Determine to wake up and do it. It's hard for many people to make that commitment early in the morning. Some wake up and simply go back to sleep. Tell yourself it's something you must do.

If I think of anything else, I'll update the list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have had an intuition about the pre-workout protein intake, but without understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to drink after the exercise. In my experience if I drink anything but water before the exercise it makes me little sloppy and less focused.

Comment: Please add sources or strong arguments. As it stands, this is only your opinion with nothing to back it up.